# sql join three table one maybe empty

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have three tables, two certainly with data values, one the values can be present or not.
This is an example schema

```
Table 1
id, username

Table 2
id, street

Table 3
id, phone_number (this can be not present)
```

please help me with query

Comment: SELECT fruitloops FROM nutclusters ORDER BY space_cadets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Username, t2.street, t3.phone_number 
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 as t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

Comment: While this may (or may not) answer the question, it would be very helpful to explain why this is supposed to work rather than just dumping the code.